# Mediaeval Latin adopted the Greek word 'grapheus' as '-gravius' (which led to Dutch/German 'graaf/Graf', "count"); where and when did this happen?

Tags: history, greek, origin, etymology, germanic

Philippa (2003–2009) says about the Dutch word *graaf*, "count", that it came from Greek *grapheus* "writer/scribe", through Mediaeval Latin *-gravius*, "royal administrative official, overseer".

Now I wonder why people in Western Europe adopted this Greek word into Latin: where did it come from, where was it used, and when was it used? The following sub-questions might be relevant:

- From which Greek tradition was it adopted? Byzantium?
- Did this adoption happen in Italy?
- When was the word adopted into Latin?
- When and where was it used in Latin?
- Didn't this word compete with *comes* "count" in Latin?
- Why does Philippa use a hyphen in *-gravius*: was it a suffix?

By no means does an answer have to answer all of these questions: any information about the adoption or use of *grapheus/-gravius* in Latin and its legacy would be appreciated.

N.B. Philippa says the word is not closely related to English *reeve/gerēfa*; although the English word probably did come from Greek *graphein* "to write", it did so by another way.

Here is part of Philippa's account:

> Wrsch. is dit woord in het Frankische gebied ontleend aan middeleeuws Latijn -grāvius ‘koninklijk bestuursambtenaar, toezichthouder’ < Grieks grapheús ‘schrijver’, zie verder → -grafie.
>
> Een Frankische graaf was oorspronkelijk een beambte met alleen uitvoerende macht, maar sinds de 6e eeuw tevens voorzitter van de mallus ‘volksvergadering, rechtsbank’ (Lex Salica).
>
> De betekenis ‘toezichthouder, bestuurder’ leeft voort in samenstellingen als → dijkgraaf ‘voorzitter van het bestuur van een waterschap’.
>
> Omdat een koninklijk bestuursambtenaar een hoge positie en dikwijls ook een titel had, ontwikkelde de betekenis zich naar ‘edelman van zekere rang’.

— http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/graaf1

Answer (score 4):

This is the most probable etymology of "Graf". It was borrowed from Byzantine Greek at about the time of Charlemagne.

http://www.dwds.de/wb/Graf

also this: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/reeve-sheriff-en-vs-graf-grebe-graaf-greve-de-nds-nl-dk-sv.3016820/